# W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(88): setKernelCountSet(10009, 0) failed with errno -2

Tags: java, android, emulation, logcat

When I run my application in the Android emulator, logcat prints out an error

```
W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(88): setKernelCountSet(10009, 0) failed with errno -2
```

Has anyone else encountered this or know why this shows up? The app seems to run normally otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

this is for traffic stats, setKernelCountSet sets uid=10009 as foreground app(1) or background app(0), in oder to stats the foreground traffic or background  traffic this app used.